# Django server shuts down

Tags: python, django

As soon as I try to switch from http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, the django server automatically shuts down, without any error. What could be the problem? I just can’t find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shut down or crash?

Comment: Like this:                                                                                                       
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 27, 2020 - 16:05:30
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[27/Feb/2020 16:05:31] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 40

C:\Users\Stepa\Python\mysite>

Comment: Just shuts down

Comment: What OS, Python version and Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.8.1, Django 3.

Comment: Are you configured admin url in urls.py?

Comment: How should it be? I have it like that: urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: It will be helpful if you post the relevant logs.

Comment: Which ones? Just code?